# Preserving and retrieving multiple js instances

Tags: javascript

i have a 'class' called myClass

```
myClass= (function(config){
    var _data, _args, _config;
    var pubdata;
    var setData = function(d){_data = d;};
    var getData function(){return _data;};
    var priFun = function(){};
    return {
       setData: setData
       getData: getData
};
})
```

in HTML js block, I initiate

```
var obj1 = myClass(config);
var obj2 = myClass(config);

globalObjList= [];
globalObjList.push({'id': 'obj1', 'obj': obj1});
globalObjList.push({'id': 'obj2', 'obj': obj2});
obj1.setData(data1);
obj2.setData(data2);
```

later on, when user perform some action, I want to retrieve obj1 or obj2 based on user's selection, so I can do further operation using the data associated with the object.

for example by clicking button1, retrieving obj1.  I want the something like

```
var obj = getInstanceById('btn1');
obj.getData(); //this should return me data1
```

I'm not sure how getInstanceById function will work.I did something like

```
getInstanceById = function(id){
    //match the id with the id in globalObjList array, and return the obj
}
```

however, this way, when get the obj this way, and do getData() it 's not the right obj that i want....

How can I do this other than declare obj1 and obj2 as global var?

Comment: @axrwkr For testing purposes, it can be just hard coded, that when clicking on btn1, send data 'obj1' to retrieve the obj obj1. there could be some type of mapping to associate with the id and obj, as shown
    {'id': 'obj1', 'obj': obj1}

Comment: @axrwkr `getInstanceById` is some function that I need to come up with, the main purpose for this function is to find the obj by some kind of id. Say I have 3 divs, and each of the div contains the instance initiated from myClass. I want the pass in the div id and then get the associated instance obj.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to have the event handlers being set in the same closure as the `new` instances. This will allow you to access the variables inside the handlers.